# How to join mongodb document on itself

Tags: mongodb

I have a document

```
{
   propertyA: [
      { name: 'jim', group: 'a'},
      { name: 'bob', group: 'a'},
      { name: 'alice', group: 'b'},
   ],
   propertyB: [
      { group: 'a', numberOfTimes: 2 }
      { group: 'b', numberOfTimes: 6 }
   ]
}
```

What I'd like to be able to achieve with an aggregate would be

```
{
    result: [
      { name: 'jim', group: 'a', numberOfTimes: 2},
      { name: 'bob', group: 'a', numberOfTimes: 2},
      { name: 'alice', group: 'b', numberOfTimes: 6},
    ]
}
```

A bit stuck as not even sure what to search for...any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- solution doesn't use lookup or unwind etc
- it does it in document level
- for each member of "propertyA" find the from propertyB the group
  and get the numberOfTimes
- merge objects to add the numberOfTimes

*the above is made assuming that all groups exists in both propertyA
and in PropertyB.(like in your sample example)
If you have groups that exists only in 1 of those properties,
if you can tell us how to handle them

[Test Code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NoUYP4Qapp-)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "result": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$propertyA",
          "in": {
            "$let": {
              "vars": {
                "nt": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$propertyB",
                    "cond": {
                      "$eq": [
                        "$$pb.group",
                        "$$pa.group"
                      ]
                    },
                    "as": "pb"
                  }
                }
              },
              "in": {
                "$mergeObjects": [
                  "$$pa",
                  {
                    "$arrayElemAt": [
                      "$$nt",
                      0
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "as": "pa"
        }
      },
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```